# What minimization problem has this solution

Tags: regression, linear-model, ridge-regression

Consider the following basic minimization problem
\begin{equation}
 {\displaystyle \min _{\beta\in R^{n}}{\frac {1}{n}}\|Y-X\beta\|_{R^{n}}^{2}},\end{equation}
with solution
\begin{equation}
{\beta^*=(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y}.
\end{equation}

Can we write down a similar and inituitive minimization problem that has a solution $\gamma^*:=A\beta^*$, where $A$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a single, unique answer because there are infinitely many functions with the same minima. By analogy to the original problem, one possibility is:

$$\min_\gamma \ \frac{1}{n} \|Y - X A^{-1} \gamma\|^2$$

**Proof**

This problem has the same form as the original (i.e. ordinary least squares regression), but the design matrix is now $X A^{-1}$ instead of $X$. Assuming $X^T X$ is invertible (as the original question did), we can solve this problem the same way:

$$\gamma^* = \big( (X A^{-1})^T (X A^{-1}) \big)^{-1} (X A^{-1})^T Y$$

This simplifies to:

$$\gamma^* = A (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$$

Plugging in $\beta^* = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$ gives:

$$\gamma^* = A \beta^*$$